# Fix viewport in browser for responsive site

Tags: css, media-queries, desktop, viewport

I designed a responsive website but now the client wants me to lock the width of the site until new changes are implemented.

When I lock the width of the container the media queries are still responding to the size of the browser screen and not the container size.

Is there a way to lock the browser viewport for desktop so that it only recognized the smaller size and uses those media queries?

My site is responsive but I want it locked to `1024px`. When I do that but view it on a larger screen width it doesn't pick up the `1024px` media query styles...

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious solution would be to comment out the other media queries, remembering to also comment out the media query declaration for the `1024px` view. For example:

```
/*
   ...

   @media ... {
       ...
   }

   @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
*/
       elem {
           ...
       }
/*
   }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('body').css('width','1024px');` with jquery

Comment: that doesnt seem to affect the viewport